# Unity post processing Bloom lags on mobile

Tags: unity, frame-rate, post-processing, lag

I made my (first) game today and noticed, that it looked kind of boring, so I decided to add some bloom to my camera and it was looking waaay better. The only problem was the performance, it dropped down from constant 60 fps to like 20-30, I looked it up in the profiler to be sure and yep, it was the post-processing, I saw mobile games which had post-processing including bloom, but these games never lagged on my phone. My phone has pretty good specs for a phone (Samsung Galaxy M20) so how do I make my post-processing performant, are there some special settings I have to make or is it just my phone?

[image: Profiler]

[image: Settings]